# Is learning AngularJS necessary before learning Angular 4-6?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I want to pursue towards becoming a FULL stack developer before that I want to get my grip on Angular.

I already know about the differences between AngularJS and Angular, my question is, 
**Is it necessary to learn AngularJS before learning Angular 4-6? 
If not, can I apply for any project/job that has a listing requirement of AngularJS?**

Summary: Can I directly learn Angular 4-6 from scratch without AngularJS?

Also, please suggest regarding which version of Angular (2-6) should be choosed to learn from scratch.

Comment: There is no need to learn angularJs before learning angular 4-6. You can directly start with the latest version of angular which is 6. This is the angular 6 https://angular.io/ learning sites or you can start learning angular from udemy.

Comment: Do you need to know C++ or Java for example, to learn Javascript? The same answer is about learning Angular and Angular.js.

Comment: Absolutely not \o/

Comment: No. You do not need to learn Angular js before angular. But once you are done with angular(2+). Then if you want to you can or not. Some legacy projects are still in Angular js. @Moiz Nadeem

Answer (score 2):

no it is not necessary to know AngularJs to lear Angular4-6 but i recommend you to first take a look on [typeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) because it is necessary before you get started with Angular4-6 you should start with Angular5 because it is latest and there is not much difference in Angular5 and Angular6 which is better for getting familiar with Angular

Answer (score 2):

You may skip AngularJS, though understanding vanilla, ECMA javascript and typescript is at must before you start to learn any kind of JS framework.

Talking about which version to start learning, I'd rather started upon learning the latest version possible, then invested some time reviewing changelog afterwards.

While you understand that tech, the latest version will become stable and popular.

Answer (score 1):

While they share many concepts, AngularJS and Angular are two completely independent frameworks. There is no need to know one before learning the other.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is very different from AngularJS. Ultimate version of AngularJS has been released so it is in sunset phase of it's life now...

http://www.codelord.net/2018/02/04/angularjs-1-dot-7-the-ultimate-version/

> Google say that in October 2017 the number of active Angular (that is,
>   2+) developers has surpassed that of AngularJS developers, which was
>   their cue all along to when they can start wrapping up 1.x.

Regarding the job - I think that future of the angularJS projects is migration to Angular/Vue/React so your Angular skills might be relevant. You may apply and let them decide.

I suggest to start learning from the most actual version which is 6 now